# How to display a hyperlink in a cell with jQuery DataTables

Tags: datatables

I have some Ajax data read into jQuery DataTables. Problem is I need to make the data in the first column into a hyperlink. As in `<td><a href = "5555.html">5555</a></td>`.

My JSON data:

```
{
   "data": [
      ["5555","07/17/2010","RCC Saturday Open","E10","Harris, Fred","1900","Nikolayev, Igor (FM)","2367","1-0"],
      ["5554","07/17/2010","RCC Saturday Open","B01","Nikolayev, Igor (FM)","2367","Motroni, Richard","1728","1-0"]
   ]
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#cccr').DataTable( {
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
         return '<a href="basic.php?game=' + data + '></a>'; //doesn't work
      },
      "ajax": 'games.json',
      "deferRender": true
   } );
} );
```

I'm not too knowledgeable about JavaScript. I was unable to figure it out after hours of googling the datatables.net website.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 18):

#### CAUSE

Option `render` should be sub-property of either `columns` or `columnDefs`.

#### SOLUTION

Use [`columnDefs.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to display hyperlink in a cell dynamically.

For example:

```js
var table = $('#cccr').DataTable({
    /* ... skipepd other options ... */
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: 0,
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                if(type === 'display'){
                    data = '<a href="basic.php?game=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
    ]      
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdpjh1u5/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you! But the jsFiddle example uses inline JSON data. I have an external JSON file of 600 records. Instead of var data = [["5555","07/17/2010",etc. I need to reference an external file.

Comment: @verlager, I just used inline JSON for demonstration. You can use external JSON if you want by using `ajax` option.

Comment: The problem is the code creates an issue where the 3rd column (date) butts up against the 2nd column on a laptop display of 1280 x 768. This may be a dataTables problem. But unless this gets fixed my web mastering days are over.

Comment: @verlager, not sure how this is related to your original question.

Answer (score -1):

configure the column definitions via [`render` option](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html):

```
"render": function ( data, type, row ) {
  return '<a href="#">' + data + '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I put that in? What do I put in for data, row, and type? I looked at https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render but it makes little sense to me. Can you please supply *exactly* what I need to do?