# jQuery datatables array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a server side data as following for a [jQuery datatable](https://datatables.net).

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": 'Hello World"
    "category": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Foo Bar"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I needs to show these "categories" as a hyperlink in the category column cells of my datatable and it should be comma seperated like following

Source: `<a href="ID">Hello World</a>, <a href="ID">Foo Bar</a>`

Example: [Hello World](http://#), [Foo Bar](http://#) etc...

I already can render this as comma separated using `"render": "[, ].title"` but not this level as as a hyperlink. Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**

```
{ data: 'category', 
    render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        $.each(data.category, function( index, value ) {
          return value.title;
        });
    }
},
```

This is what I have done so far. But still not working. All I needs to pass title and id into this loop. So I can use it to build a hyperlink.

Comment: `render` also accepts a function `render: function ( data, type, row )` so just build the list of hyperlinks there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a hyperlink in a cell with jQuery DataTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778648/how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell-with-jquery-datatables)

Comment: @PaulAbbott: I used it as a function, I'm able to turn this into a comma separated hyperlinks for the first level, but not in this category level, I'm having a trouble retrieving title and id into this function. I know `data.category.title` is the trick but it is not working for this second level.

Comment: @dsh: No. This is not a duplicate of the question you mentioned. This is not just a hyperlink in a cell, this is slightly different because i'm asking about a array object. Not just an array.

Comment: `data.category` is an array so `data.category.title` is not going to work.  You need to loop over `data.category`.

Comment: @PaulAbbott: Can you help me on this please. How to loop over in such scenarios ? Looks like you are going to be a lifesaver !

Comment: @stackminu  Update your question to show the code you have, then. Your question currently doesn't show your attempt at defining a *function* for the column's rendering. Just as in the question I linked, define a function and return a string. In the body of your function you will need to loop through the array as PaulAbbott indicates.

Comment: @dsh I've edited my question. Can you help me ?

Comment: @PaulAbbott: I've edited my question. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty blind here without more context, but...

```
{ data: 'category', 
    render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
        var result = '';
        $.each(full.category, function( index, value ) {
          result = result + '<a href="' + value.id + '">' + value.title + '</a>';
          if (index < full.category.length)
              result = result + ', ';
        });
        return result;
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just tried this. Getting an eror `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: As I said you were a lifesaver. I just changed `data` to `full` and everything works fine. \m/ Thanks a lot.