# jQuery DataTables: Hyperlink in a cell (data source: Mysql table)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

My question is a follow-up to the previous one:
[How to display a hyperlink in a cell with jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778648/how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell-with-jquery-datatables)

There is also a Fiddle link [provided](https://jsfiddle.net/vdpjh1u5/)

I now have the same question, except that my data source is Mysql database table.

In essence, I am now struggling to implement the "rendering of links" while the source "Data" comes from Mysql table (for instance, the values "5555" and "5554" that are linked in the previous example are values in cells in a mysql table).

My understanding (or assumption really) is that the key herein lies within the javascript part previously provided (the "data" source reference as well as the "rendering" part): (the following is simply the "local data sourcing" example provided in the previous answer, this is not the code I use, my code comes second below)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var data = [["5555","07/17/2010","RCC Saturday Open","E10","Harris,  Fred","1900","Nikolayev, Igor (FM)","2367","1-0"],["5554","07/17/2010","RCC Saturday Open","B01","Nikolayev, Igor (FM)","2367","Motroni, Richard","1728","1-0"]];

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets:0,
                render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                    if(type === 'display'){
                        data = '<a href="basic.php?game=' + encodeURIComponent(data) + '">' + data + '</a>';
                    }

                    return data;
                }
            }
        ]      
    });

});
```

And here is the base-code I am working with currently where I need to incorporate the "data location data" and "rendering" part to get the hyperlinks working:

```
function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
   "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,

    "ajax" : {
            url:"fetch.php",
            type:"POST"
    }
   });
```

My data fetching part is working well via the "fetch.php", but I just don´t know how do I achieve the working links given the data source in my case is external mysql table.

EDIT: Original question resolved. Thank you to @Charlietfl!

EDIT 2: One follow-up question regarding the "GET"-like resemblance of passing variable over the link vs. is the same possible via "POST"? so the links would not become bookmarkable for security purposes?

Comment: You need the same columnDefs regardless of data source. Is data structure being sent from php the same as the hard code sample array?

Comment: Thank you for quick response, Charlietfl! Yes, I am using that exact same data structure. I just don´t know what do I need add or modify in my code to enable rendering hyperlinks from external data.

Comment: should be identical `columnDef`'s as in static version. The internal rendering works the same regardless of data source

Comment: ok, but what do I do about the line: "var data = [["5555","07/17/2010","RCC...". ... do I just delete it as my data comes from external source? In the first example this data is hard-coded so I need to get rid of this line?

Comment: Yes... or temporarily comment it out in case you need it to debug with and delete when all works as expected

Comment: and what about this line: "data: data,"?

Comment: comment that out...it is superseded by the ajax

Comment: Great. Works! Thank you, Charlietfl!

Comment: One follow-up if I may. The current solution provides linking capability based on "GET" functionality on the URL address. Is it also possible to do this via POST functionality? (for security reasons, so that links would not reveal the second part of basic.php?game=xyz... on the address bar? ( I don´t want these to be bookmarkable links)

Comment: Could render a form in each cell that uses post method. Or if you don't need full page reload can use ajax when element is clicked

Comment: ok. I am just thinking the same, thought that will probably be very complex to generating a form in each and every cell of DataTables output table. I will keep working on this to see if I can somehow make it happen. If not, I will post a new separate question for that, if needed. Thank you again, Charlietfl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using external data source is not different as with using JavaScript-sourced data, just remove [`data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/data) option and replace it with [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option.

Please note that hiding variable in a POST request does not improve security in any way. Any request can be inspected in a console.

Also there could be other ways to display target page only if visited from original page, like checking referrer or using a session cookie.

However you could create a hidden form and POST to a page as shown below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu'
    },
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets:0,
            render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                if(type === 'display'){
                    data = '<a class="link-post" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/">' + data + '</a>';
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Handle click on link in the table
$('#example').on('click', '.link-post', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   // Get row data
   var data = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();

   var form = $('#frm-main').get(0);

   // Update form action URL if needed
   form['action'] = this.href;

   // Set required form parameters
   form['name'].value = data[0];

   // Submit form
   form.submit();   
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0Lnm3kj/3/) for demonstration on how this could be implemented.

Comment: This looks great, many thanks, Gyrocode! Perhaps a "cosmetics" question - how would you get the clickable link to open target="_blank"? I added/incorporated this suffix to the end of the a href line but to my surprise it had no effect - clicking on a link keeps reloading the page itself, and does not open a new page. 

data = '<a class="link-post" href="https://www.gyrocode.com/" target="_blank">' + data + '</a>';

<-- somehow this does not open the link in a NEW window..

Comment: Found a solution. Had to add:   <base target="_blank"> inside the <head> section of the webpage.

Comment: Setting the target attribute to `_blank` in the `<base>` element will cause **all** on-page links to open in a new tab, You may not want that behaviour.  Using `target="_blank"` as you have shown should work fine, it looks like you have a typo though - see the semicolon just before `target`.

Comment: @Eleanor, you need to add `target="_blank"` to the `form` element, not the link.

Comment: Thank you, all, especially @Gyrocode! You helped me along tremendously!