# Customise value of columns while using server side processing of jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using server side processing in jquery datatable.

html

```
 <table id="agent-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>UPN</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Agent Queue</th>
      <th>Inbound Calls</th>
      <th>Outbound Calls</th>
      <th>Total Time On Call</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="agent-table-body">
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>UPN</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Agent Queue</th>
      <th>Inbound Calls</th>
      <th>Outbound Calls</th>
      <th>Total Time On Call</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

js

```
 let table = $('#agent-table').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
    "url": "/call-record-api/data-table/",
    "type": "GET"
  },
  "columns": [
  {"data": "upn"},
  {"data": "department"},
  {"data": "agent_queue"},
  {"data": "num_inbound"},
  {"data": "num_outbound"},
  {"data": "custom_call_time"},
  {"data": "last_presence_status"}
  ]
});
```

I want to customize how data is added to the row. e.g wrapping `num_inbound` and `num_outbound` in `href` and adding other html elements etc.

Here is how row is being shown right now

```
<tr>
   <td> myname@example.com </td>
   <td> Sales </td>
   <td> Test </td>
   <td> 5 </td>
   <td> 9 </td>
   <td> 01:10:00 </td>
   <td> Busy </td>
</tr>
```

I want to customize row like this

```
<tr>
   <td> myname@example.com </td>
   <td> Sales </td>
   <td> Test </td>
   <td> <a href="#" onclick="getData(this)" data-link="/call-record-api/agent-data/myname@example.com/Inbound/">5</a> </td>
   <td> <a href="#" onclick="getData(this)" data-link="/call-record-api/agent-data/myname@example.com/Outbound/">9</a> </td>
   <td> 01:10:00 </td>
   <td> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-lg red-light"></i> Busy </td>
</tr>
```

Can you please guide how can i do the customization?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display a hyperlink in a cell with jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778648/how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell-with-jquery-datatables). The linked answer uses `columnDefs` - but you can stick with your existing `columns` if you prefer - in which case you do not need the `targets: 0` option.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks ! I went through the question that you shared. I understood that i need to define render for each column that i want to customize. Can you please tell how can i access ```targets:0``` value in render function of ```tagrets:3``` ? I need agent upn while constructing href for  ```tagrets:3``` and  ```tagrets:4```

Comment: Use the `row` variable from `"render": function ( data, type, row ) {...}`. So, for example, `row.upn`.  You can also add a `console.log( row );` statement to the body of the render function to check exactly what the row data looks like.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks ! i got it. You have always helped me whenever i raise question regarding datatable.

Comment: Happy to help. If you feel your approach may be helpful to others, you are welcome to provide an answer yourself - and also accept it.

Comment: @andrewjames I accepted the feedback that this question already has answers, so i cannot answer it now. But i used the ```render``` function to customize the value. Instead of ```columnDefs``` , i used ```columns```.  So in my solution i customized inbound column like this:  ```{"data": "num_inbound",render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) { return '<a href="#" onclick="getData(this)" data-link="/call-record-api/agent-data/'+row.upn+'/Inbound/">'+data+'</a>' }}```

Answer (score 0):

In the AJAX call you can edit the data generated into the table, add the following event, in your AJAX method.

createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {

```
var createdBy = $(row).find("td:eq(2)"); // third column in row.
```

**// within this method you can edit your datatable data, row per row, after the data is generated, following is an example, try it out, hope it helps.**

```
if(createdBy.text() == "James"){
createdBy.css("font-weight", "bold");
```

}

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have not already done so, you can take the [tour].

Comment: You may also want to edit your answer to fix its formatting. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i went with the standard approach suggested by @andrewjames. I couldn't try your solution so i cannot accept it. Sorry and thanks for devoting your time to this question.